# fluid height for nested div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the green div's height to be fluid when adding content in the blue div, the red div work as spected but not the green one.

So I want the green div to be as fluid as the red one when adding content to the blu div.
Here is the code http://jsbin.com/ivobav/1/edit

Comment: Unless you put the red div inside the green div, there is no automatic way to do it.

Comment: @entonio that's not what I did?

Comment: Sorry, when I looked at it I could swear I saw it close before the start of the red div. My mistake.

Comment: @entonio it happens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have multiple things at play here.  First, if you want a fluid height on green div, you need to remove `height: 90%` from the CSS.  You will notice this will make your green div disappear (because it has no relative positioned content in it).

If you type something in the green div, you will notice it grows.  Now, I am assuming you want the red div to nest inside the green div.  In order to do this, you need to remove the absolute positioning on the red div.

If you do this, the red div now disappears.  That is because the blue div is floated inside of it, meaning it will not grow to hold the blue div.  So simply add `overflow: auto;` to the red div and you should get what you want.

See the results here:

http://jsbin.com/ivobav/5/edit

Comment: Hi, Well now from your solution, is it possible to fill the yellow div's height to 100% no matter its content? with this new code: http://jsbin.com/ivobav/14/edit

Answer (score 0):

This happens because parents don't stretch to fit their float children. To go around this problem, you may either:

- not use floats
- insert the equivelent of `<div style="clear:both"></div>` as the last element in the parent container
- have otherwise non-floated content inside the parent

**Edit**: For a more thorough explanation, look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html. Mike's answer is the best way to do it, but unfortunately it won't work on all occasions. Notice that while this seems like a problem for which people have tried to come up with solutions, it's not actually a bug, it's the spec - cue someone to introduce some new standard CSS property to make an element to stretch to fit its floats...