# Container not resizing for child div

Tags: html, css

[Click here for visual](http://waly1039.com/content/page/everything-kitchen-sink#overlay-context=content/page/everything-kitchen-sink)

As you can see from the picture, my parent container is not expanding to fit my child container.  The page container (#contain) actually stops at the bottom left hand corner of the kitchen photograph. The child container (#zone2) is clearly overflowing outside its parent container (#contain).  I would like to be able to have (#contain) expand automatically to fit (#zone2).  The CSS is:

```
#contain {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 px;
    background: #E3DCCC;
    z-index: 0;
}

#zone1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    background: url(http://waly1039.com/sites/default/files/k4.jpg) no-repeat center   top;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#head {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
}

#head img {
    max-width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#zone2 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
    top: 360px;
    float: right;
    right: 15px;
    width: 53%;
    height: auto;
    border: 4px solid #715E40;
    background-color: white;
}
#zone2 img {
      max-width:100%;
      height: auto;
      float:left;
      margin: 5px;
}

#zone3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 710px;
    left: 15px;
    float: left;
    height: 340px;
    width: 38%;
    border: 4px solid #715E40;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Then you need to clear the floats: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html That article explains it and gives some solutions, but there are others if those wont work. Just google it - its a common task.

Comment: I think the problem is that all its content is floated. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992887/fluid-height-for-nested-div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a float issue.  Try adding the traditional CSS clear fix to #zone2's container:

```
.container:after{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

Be sure to put this in the :after pseudo selector, otherwise it won't work for you.  Floated elements exist outside of normal document flow, which is why the container isn't expanding to contain them.  The clear fix forces the floats to be cleared, which will cause the container to expand around the bottom of this element.

Answer (score 0):

I tested adding more images to `#zone2` and `#contain` expands vertically.  Somehow you've got an element(s) in `#zone2` with padding or margins that aren't being added to the parent's total height.

If you want a quick fix in order to move on then add `margin-bottom: 30px;` to `#zone2`.

Answer (score 0):

I've duplicated your problem and was able to resolve it with this: You might want to try it. It's looks a bit odd so make a class for it if you like. I'm more concern with where it is placed.

Just beneath lines of your code, add my third line. Just that and you are done. Note, it more about positioning.

```
<div id="zone3"></div>
<div id="zoneclear"></div>
<br style="clear:both; float:none; display:block; height:1px;" />
```

Just add the third line.

and just modify one of your styles:

```
#zoneclear {   
    clear: both;
    float:none;
    display:block;  
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[EDIT]
The codes have a serious bug in firefox which is not present in Google Chrome (that I tested in earlier due to your relative positioning. So I've modified the #zoneclear style to fix that. You might have to test if the other browsers like this hack.

I hope it helps you

Comment: These three lines do the trick well. Tested in Google Chrome!

Comment: Page has been changing, it seems you are working on it at the same time. You could move the styles to zoneclear and make two of it. Same codes, Positioning is everything.

Comment: Please try the update in the #zoneclear above. Fill the style with these new values. That should fix the firefox issue.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their responses; I've tried all of the suggestions listed with little success. I can get everything placed correctly so that it looks nice on different browsers, the issue occurs when I try and view page on a cell phone.  Zone2 contains 2x2 images (12 total) perfectly fine, however - when you shrink the screen to simulate what a cell phone might look like - the multi-color boxes inside switch to a single column that pushes well beyond the page container's boundaries...which makes zero sense to me since that seems to be the whole point of a page container.

Comment: Oh boy, you're just mentioning cell phones and we've been fighting with Chrome and Firefox. Cellphones are unpredictable as they might act differently. Blackberries, Opera mini, Androids do not all behave the same. Your site uses relative positioning with top left right settings. Something I don't think some cellphones can handle. I'd suggest you create a responsive design or just make a separate design for mobiles, detect the browsers and server those pages or css. As for your current design and layout, well that would take a lot of work.

Comment: Yea, agreed - I've conceded to be happy that this current layout works across browsers. As you put it, "it would take a lot of work" to change at this point. Thanks again for the input though, it was much appreciated; Happy coding!

Comment: Yap, you too. But you could still pick answer for those that help fix the web browser issues. A way of saying thank you for the time. For mobile, think RWD. Most times, the 100% fluid width principles works better. You could do mobile browser detection with codeigniter, Jquery or even scripts from detectmobilebrowsers.com. I'm sure you have a way to figure that out. Great design you have there.